# how to pass user's login token to socket.io?

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

how do I pass custom login's token to io connection?

So basically after I have authenticate a user, and the user will have the token, but how do I pass that token to socket.io connection and probably use it.

Here's the code --  this is in api.js

```
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  // I skip alot of codes for clarity
  var token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers['x-access-token'];

   if (token) {
      req.user = user;
      return next();
   }
}
//Login 
router.post('/login', function(req, res) {
        // I skip the mongoose part for clarity
        var token = createToken(user);

        res.json({
          success: true,
          message: "Successfully login",
          token: token
        });
});
```

while this is in server.js

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {

  socket.broadcast.emit('user joined', {
    username: socket.username,
    numUsers: numUsers
  });

  socket.on('typing', function() {
    socket.broadcast.emit('typing', {
      username: socket.username
    });
  });

 socket.on('online', function() {
    socket.emit('online');
  });

  socket.on('chat', function(msg) {
    console.log("message: " + msg);
    io.emit('chat', msg);
  });

});
```

As you can see if I have to set the username object i have to do `username: socket.username`, to use the username object.

If i do username: req.user , it will return error. Do i have to set `ensureAuthenticated` function in the `io.on('connection')` to be able to use it?

Answer (score 3):

On any incoming socket message, you can access the cookies that were present when the socket was first connected via:

```
socket.request.headers.cookie
```

So, if your user login token is in a cookie, you can fetch it from there for any connected socket.io socket.

---

You can also do socket authentication at connect time using socket.io middleware as shown here: [Authentication with Node/Express/Socket.IO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26224377/authentication-with-node-express-socket-io)

Sample code in the socket.io doc [here](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#namespace#use(fn:function):namespace).

```
var io = require('socket.io')();
io.use(function(socket, next){
  if (socket.request.headers.cookie) return next();
  next(new Error('Authentication error'));
});
```